# Errors when passing variable to awk

Tags: variables, awk

I'm trying to pass external variable into awk using `awk -v`
but just cannot figure out what's my problem!

```
for ((c=1;c<=22;c++));do cat hg19.gap.bed|awk -v var={chr"$c"} '{if ("$1"=="$var") print}' > $var.cbs;done
```

What's the problem of this command?
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In awk, only the field variables start with a `$`.   And you don't want the double quotes within awk.  Try `if ($1 == var) ...`.

Using `$var` actually means the field at the index stored in `var`, in this case not a valid field (but you can use it to iterate over the fields).

Answer (score 1):

What is the `var={chr"$c"}` supposed to produce?

What it does produce in this context is `{chr1}`, `{chr2}`, ..., `{chr22}`.

Note that the variable `var` is an `awk` variable and not a shell variable. You'd have to redirect to `"{chr$c}.cbs"` to get the 22 separate files.   Within the script, `$var` will always be `$0` since `var` evaluated as a number is `0`.

Rather than running the command 22 times, you can surely do it all in one pass.  Assuming that you are using [`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) (GNU `Awk`) or `awk` on MacOS X (BSD) or any POSIX-compliant [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), you can write:

```
awk '$1 ~ /\{chr([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[012])\}/ {file=$1".cbs"; print $0 >file;}' hg19.gap.bed
```

This does the whole job in one pass through the data file.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that chr is just some string and you want to make match with chr1, chr2,....

```
for ((c=1;c<=22;c++));do cat hg19.gap.bed | awk -v var=chr"$c" '"$1"==var {print}' > chr"$c".cbs;done
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No quotes on `$1` and you can drop the action entirely as it's the default.